# Optimal partition search

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions, combinatorial-optimization

Given an integer $n$, and 2 real sequences $\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$ and $\{b_1, \dots, b_n\}$, with $a_i$, $b_i$ > 0, for all $i$. For a fixed $m < n$ let $\{P_1, \dots, P_m\}$ be a partition of the set $\{1, \dots, n\}$ as in $P_1 \cup \dots \cup P_m$ = $\{1, \dots, n\}$, with the $P_i$'s pairwise disjoint. I wish to find a partition of size $m$ that solves

$$\max_{P=\{P_1, ..., P_m\}}\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{(\sum_{i \in P_j}a_i)^2}{\sum_{i \in P_j}b_i}$$

I am really looking for an algorithm which solves the problem in polynomial time, a brute-force solution is not feasible, as it would involve the a Bell number of order $(n, k)$, with $n$ over 1e6 for realistic cases.

I would be happy to prove that the partition is monotonic in increasing values of $a/b$, in the sense that a partition expressed in the indices of the two sequences $a, b$, sorted by increasing values of $a/b$ will contain monotonic, increasing sets of integers in $1, ..., n$. I believe this is the case - can someone provide a proof?

If so, the brute-force search could be improved to an order $n \choose m-1$ algorithm, still long, but a significant savings.

The script below solves the problem by brute-force. For example, a sample run with $n = 12$, $m = 3$, gives an optimal partition of (expressed in indices of the sorted sequence $a/b$):

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11]]
```

which is monotonic, as claimed.

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import concurrent.futures
from functools import partial
from itertools import chain, islice

# n
NUM_POINTS = 12
# m
PARTITION_SIZE = 4

rng = np.random.RandomState(55)

def knuth_partition(ns, m):
    def visit(n, a):
        ps = [[] for i in range(m)]
        for j in range(n):
            ps[a[j + 1]].append(ns[j])
        return ps

    def f(mu, nu, sigma, n, a):
        if mu == 2:
            yield visit(n, a)
        else:
            for v in f(mu - 1, nu - 1, (mu + sigma) % 2, n, a):
                yield v
        if nu == mu + 1:
            a[mu] = mu - 1
            yield visit(n, a)
            while a[nu] > 0:
                a[nu] = a[nu] - 1
                yield visit(n, a)
        elif nu > mu + 1:
            if (mu + sigma) % 2 == 1:
                a[nu - 1] = mu - 1
            else:
                a[mu] = mu - 1
            if (a[nu] + sigma) % 2 == 1:
                for v in b(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                    yield v
            else:
                for v in f(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                    yield v
            while a[nu] > 0:
                a[nu] = a[nu] - 1
                if (a[nu] + sigma) % 2 == 1:
                    for v in b(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                        yield v
                else:
                    for v in f(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                        yield v

    def b(mu, nu, sigma, n, a):
        if nu == mu + 1:
            while a[nu] < mu - 1:
                yield visit(n, a)
                a[nu] = a[nu] + 1
            yield visit(n, a)
            a[mu] = 0
        elif nu > mu + 1:
            if (a[nu] + sigma) % 2 == 1:
                for v in f(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                    yield v
            else:
                for v in b(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                    yield v
            while a[nu] < mu - 1:
                a[nu] = a[nu] + 1
                if (a[nu] + sigma) % 2 == 1:
                    for v in f(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                        yield v
                else:
                    for v in b(mu, nu - 1, 0, n, a):
                        yield v
            if (mu + sigma) % 2 == 1:
                a[nu - 1] = 0
            else:
                a[mu] = 0
        if mu == 2:
            yield visit(n, a)
        else:
            for v in b(mu - 1, nu - 1, (mu + sigma) % 2, n, a):
                yield v

    n = len(ns)
    a = [0] * (n + 1)
    for j in range(1, m + 1):
        a[n - m + j] = j - 1
    return f(m, n, 0, n, a)

def Bell_n_k(n, k):
    ''' Number of partitions of {1,...,n} into
        k subsets, a restricted Bell number
    '''
    if (n == 0 or k == 0 or k > n): 
        return 0
    if (k == 1 or k == n): 
        return 1

    return (k * Bell_n_k(n - 1, k) + 
                Bell_n_k(n - 1, k - 1))

def slice_partitions(partitions):
    # Have to consume it; can't split work on generator
    partitions = list(partitions)
    num_partitions = len(partitions)

    bin_ends = list(range(0,num_partitions,int(num_partitions/NUM_WORKERS)))
    bin_ends = bin_ends + [num_partitions] if num_partitions/NUM_WORKERS else bin_ends
    islice_on = list(zip(bin_ends[:-1], bin_ends[1:]))

    rng.shuffle(partitions)
    slices = [list(islice(partitions, *ind)) for ind in islice_on]
    return slices

def reduce(return_values, fn):
    return fn(return_values, key=lambda x: x[0])

class SimpleTask(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __call__(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        return '{self.a} * {self.b} = {product}'.format(self=self, product=self.a * self.b)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{self.a} * {self.b}'.format(self=self)

class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, partition):
        self.partition = partition
        self.task = partial(Task._task, a, b)

    def __call__(self):
        return self.task(self.partition)

    @staticmethod
    def _task(a, b, partitions, report_each=1000):
        max_sum = float('-inf')
        arg_max = -1
        for ind,part in enumerate(partitions):
            val = 0
            part_val = [0] * len(part)
            part_vertex = [0] * len(part)
            for part_ind, p in enumerate(part):
                part_sum = sum(a[p])**2/sum(b[p])
                part_vertex[part_ind] = part_sum
                part_val[part_ind] = part_sum
                val += part_sum
            if val > max_sum:
                max_sum = val
                arg_max = part
                max_part_vertex = part_vertex
            # if not ind%report_each:
            #     print('Percent complete: {:.{prec}f}'.
            #           format(100*len(slices)*ind/num_partitions, prec=2))
        return (max_sum, arg_max, max_part_vertex)

class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, task_queue, result_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self):
        proc_name = self.name
        while True:
            task = self.task_queue.get()
            if task is None:
                # print('Exiting: {}'.format(proc_name))
                self.task_queue.task_done()
                break
            result = task()
            self.task_queue.task_done()
            self.result_queue.put(result)

NUM_WORKERS = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
INT_LIST= range(0, NUM_POINTS)

num_partitions = Bell_n_k(NUM_POINTS, PARTITION_SIZE)
partitions = knuth_partition(INT_LIST, PARTITION_SIZE)

slices = slice_partitions(partitions)

while True:
    a0 = rng.uniform(low=-0.0, high=100.0, size=NUM_POINTS)
    b0 = rng.uniform(low=-0.0, high=100.0, size=NUM_POINTS)

    # sort by increasing a/b, to check claim
    ind = np.argsort(a0/b0)
    (a,b) = (seq[ind] for seq in (a0,b0))

    tasks = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    results = multiprocessing.Queue()
    workers = [Worker(tasks, results) for i in range(NUM_WORKERS)]
    num_slices = len(slices) # should be the same as NUM_WORKERS

    for worker in workers:
        worker.start()

    for i,slice in enumerate(slices):
        tasks.put(Task(a, b, slice))

    for i in range(NUM_WORKERS):
        tasks.put(None)

    tasks.join()

    allResults = list()
    slices_left = num_slices
    while not results.empty():
        result = results.get()
        allResults.append(result)
        # print('result: {!r}'.format(result))
        slices_left -= 1

    r_max = reduce(allResults, max)

    c = a/b
    part = r_max[1]
    endpoints = [(a[-1], b[0]) for a,b in zip(part[:-1], part[1:])]
    d = [(c[r]-c[l]) for l,r in endpoints]
    r = [(c[r]-c[l])/c[l] for l,r in endpoints]
    all_diffs = np.concatenate([[np.nan], np.diff(c)]) 
    all_rets = np.concatenate([np.diff(c), [np.nan]]) / c
    max_diffs = sorted(all_diffs)[-(PARTITION_SIZE-1):]
    max_rets = sorted(all_rets)[-(PARTITION_SIZE-1):]
    print('TRIAL: {} : max: {:4.6f} pttion: {!r}'.format(i, *r_max[:-1]))

    # print('TRIAL: {} : max: {:4.6f} {!r} {!r}'.format(i, *r_max[:-1],
    #                                                [float(x)
    #                                                 for x in ['{0:0.2f}'.format(i)
    #                                                           for i in r_max[2]]], prec=2))

    try:
        assert all(np.diff(list(chain.from_iterable(r_max[1]))) == 1)
    except AssertionError as e:
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: If you can prove the monotonicity, you can find an optimal partition by solving a shortest path problem in a directed acyclic layered graph with $O(mn)$ nodes and $O(mn^2)$ arcs.

Comment: That could be solved in$O((m + n) \log(mn))$ time. I don't see it though, I don't see even a 2nd order algorithm in $mn$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the monotonicity property, here is a shortest-path formulation.  The nodes are $(i,k)$, where $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $k\in\{1,\dots,m\}$, plus a dummy sink node $(n+1,m+1)$.  The directed arcs are from $(i,k)$ to $(j,k+1)$, where $i<j$, with the interpretation that items $i,\dots,j-1$ appear in part $P_k$.  The arc cost, which depends only on $i$ and $j$, is: $$\frac{-\left(\sum_{r=i}^{j-1} a_r\right)^2}{\sum_{r=i}^{j-1} b_r},$$
negated because your original problem is maximization.  The source node is $(1,1)$, and you want to find a shortest path from the source to the sink.  Note that the network is acyclic, so you don't even need Dijkstra's algorithm.  Bellman's (dynamic programming) equations can be solved in one backwards pass starting from the sink node.

Comment: Yes, I agree. We have fewer edges, naive count gives $n(n-1)/2$ but there is also padding - we shouldn't connect $(1, 1)$ to $(2, n-1)$  if $m >= 3$ for example.

Comment: Right, and some nodes aren't reachable from $(1,1)$, like $(1,k)$ for $k>1$.  But still $O(n)$ nodes and $O(n^2)$ arcs for each of the $m$ layers.  I guess you meant $(n-1,2)$ instead of $(2,n-1)$.  Each arc increments the layer by exactly 1.